# Finding the solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Note: $u$ is independent of $t$.

Let $u_l$ be the solution for $u_t = 2u_{xx}$ where $u(0)=0$. Let $u_r$ be the solution for $u_t = u_{xx}$ where $u(5)=10$.

However, $u_l(3)=u_r(3)$ and $2\partial_x u_l(3) = \partial_x u_r (3)$.

Comment: $u$ independent of $t$? So $u_t = 0$?

Comment: Based on the notation I would assume that $x$ and $t$ are independent variables. In which case, $u$ is a function of both $x$ and $t$. So I'm not understanding what things like "$u(5)$" should mean. Later you are differentiating $u(3)$ with respect to $x$, so is $u(\mbox{some value})$ supposed to be a function of $x$?

Comment: Also, now that I have finished reading your post, what is your question?

Comment: Yes $u_t =0$. My question is what are the functions of $u_l$ and $u_r$.

Comment: if $u_t=0$ then the solution is easily found and this equation looses all of its interest as it becomes an ODE which has a quadratic solution (see answer below).

Did you perhaps misread the question?

Answer (score 0):

$u_l$ and $u_r$ are not unique:
$$\begin{align}
u_l(x)&=A\,x\\
u_r(x)&=10+B(x-5).
\end{align}
$$
When $A=B=2$ both coincide.